# OpenAPI Specification 3.0 shows different url in browser and Servers dropdown

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, openapi-generator

[image]

We are using OpenApi Specification v1.4.8. We have load balancer urls and domain url. Domain url `http://market.place.com/productsservice/swagger-ui.html` and load balancer url is `http://7649263.path.aws.com/productsservice/swagger-ui.html`.

Due some ongoing network issue with the domain, we have shifted to use load balancer url for testing the application. When I access swagger ui using the above load balancer url, I see the domain URL in servers dropdown(haven't added it anywhere). Thus the url in browser address bar and in Servers dropdown is different.

Since Swagger uses the base url from 'Servers' dropdown to fabricate paths for testing, and my domain is not working, I am not able to fire request from Swagger UI. The request work fine via postman when the url in browser that is load balancer url is used.

Is there some configuration which can make the Servers dropdown URL and Browser url base path same ? What we are trying to do is, the Servers dropdown needs to take the url as in the address bar of browser.

Comment: URL base paths are fabricated so as not to expose the exact url details.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have  `openapi 3 configuration java class`.

You should

> new OpenAPI().addServersItem(...)

Edit your method like this.

```js
    
    private String ip="109.162.230.178";   //your ip

    private String port="8587";   //your port

    // if you have context add this line
    private String context="tws";   //your context

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .addServersItem(new Server().url("http://"+ip+":"+port+"/"+context))
               ...
    }
```

now your UI Combobox is like this :
[image: combobox]

For example my server static ip is

> 109.162.230.178

and i have to use this **Openapi 3 UI**

from another computer outside of my local network in Internet.

Comment: If we hardcode ip/port, then for each environment(dev/test/prod) we need a separate code base or rather separate configuration properties file ?  Is there some way out via code which can get the Servers base path ?

Comment: Yes . Definitely , get your configuration from application.properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think of the one reason why you have this issue. You should check in code if *io.swagger.v3.oas.models.servers.Server* is being used in OpenAPI configuration-

```
OpenAPI oas = new OpenAPI();
......
......
String url = "/market.place.com/"
List<Server> servers = new ArrayList<Server>();
Server server = new Server();
server.setUrl(url);
servers.add(server);
oas.setServers(servers);
```

If you are relying on programmatic approach for openAPI configuration and you have something like above in your code then that may be the reason why you are seeing your domain URI. You can replace it with correct URI to make it work.